# Grasemonkey - Change Design (CSS)

Tags: firefox, javascript, css

i need your help. I want to change with Grasemonkey a Design (CSS Code). Only the Colors.

This Page is light and i want change the light colors to dark. How i do that?
www.cp.roleplay-gaming.net

Comment: Your link is bad.

Comment: https://cp.roleplay-gaming.net

Comment: Sorry, this website wants a login, so can't do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with Greasemonkey, but it appears you can add a user script to override some base CSS.

The code below, for example, would change the background color to a dark color on the login page at the site you shared above. The catch? It only works on Greasemonkey version < 4.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Override default styles, turn light to dark
// @include /https?\:\/\/([a-z\.]*\.)?cp.roleplay-gaming\.net\/.*/
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( `
    body {
        background-color: #222;
    }
    .loginColumns .row div:nth-child(2){
        color: white;
    }
    /* add other CSS here */
` );
```

For Greasemonkey > version 4, looks like this function broke, though. So instead, you'll have to use some javascript, like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Override default styles, turn light to dark
// @include /https?\:\/\/([a-z\.]*\.)?cp.roleplay-gaming\.net\/.*/
// ==/UserScript==

function GM_addStyle(cssStr){

    var n = document.createElement('style');
    n.type = "text/css";
    n.innerHTML = cssStr;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(n);

}

GM_addStyle("
    body {
        background-color: #222;
    }
    .loginColumns .row div:nth-child(2){
        color: white;
    }
");
```

In either approach, add the styles you want, then save this file as `darker.user.js`. Next, follow the instructions at https://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:Installing_Scripts to install. Enjoy!